# Android speech-to-text shows Google logo

Tags: android

Our Android application uses RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH activity. When the activity is launched, it actually displays Google's logo. Looks like this activity is not really part of Android SDK but a contribution from Google. This is fine for our use. My issue is slightly different.

I am working on a dialog box that displays third-party copyright notices. Do I need to mention something like "Speech recognition is powered by Google?" I could not find any licensing document on this component.

Comment: I don't think so, since it's an API on the device, not a code library that you're licensing. Crediting the speech recognition would be similar to crediting Google for the Holo theme or the View widgets that are built into Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenfour04 had answered this in his comments. I also received a few replies on Android Developer's forum. Here is the gist:

The application is using a generic intent. It is requesting the phone if there is a speech recognition app installed and it just sends a request to that app to do the work for you. Some phones may have a different app installed or more than one. If the phone has more than one such app, the user gets to pick what your app uses for this function.

As the application is using a generic intent without knowing which other app actually handles speech recognition, no attribution is required.